# Select different layout for specific page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a website in `Wordpress` and I am using `Draftly` theme. It shows right side bar for all the pages. I can hide it from theme but it will hide it for every page. I want to hide it for only few pages. Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it only by css, in wordpress every page have an id you can find it in the class of the body tag if you inspect .
so to hide an element only in a specific page you can do for exemple :

```
.page-id-304 .class-of-the-element-to-hide{

display : none !important;

}
```

replace the id of the page with your id

Comment: Thank you so much.